# does js files impede the building of war files

Tags: javascript, deployment, war

I know this may sound stupid, but does js files impede the building of war files?

I am working with my colleague and he is saying that building the war file takes longer with the bunch of js files in our project. I don't think it will but i can't find the answer.

Comment: If you have hundreds of files it may take longer to copy and archive them all. So you should have a look at you build script to see if you copy them several times to different locations and think if you can avoid doing it.

Comment: @jared as in the building time of the war file will take longer.

Comment: @Igor yeah we have got hundreds of js files in the project but that is just copying them and I doubt we have duplicates.

Comment: @jonleech It depends how many times you copy them to different locations. Depending on what you use to build your project the solution might be different. For Ant you could define a `fileset` for JavaScript files and then include it when creating war. This could save some time. How much time does it take to build a project now?

Comment: @Igor well i think my colleague is doing that. the project takes about 10 mins to build at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not enough information to answer your question. However, your co-worker may be correct. A WAR file is simply a ZIP file with a different extension. However, when you *build* a WAR file, many things generally happen. Your build procedure will usually do things like compiling Java files, creating metadata files, etc. It's also possible that it performs concatenation, validation, and-or minimization of JavaScript files.

If your build process does optimize or validate JavaScript, then the number of JavaScript files might actually matter. However, this isn't necessarily a bad thing. You probably don't want to overdo it without reason, but it isn't a problem as long as your build process does the necessary minimization steps.

Now, if your build process does not do anything to process JavaScript files, then your co-worker might be talking about another performance concern: Page load times. Having a bunch of JavaScript files to retrieve can have a significant impact on page load times for your users because of the amount of overhead in making a separate HTTP request for each file. This is further amplified in high latency situations like with mobile users. That's why JavaScript minimization and concatenation steps are often included in modern build procedures.

So it's possible your co-worker was mistaken about the reason for the performance concern, but was correct in suggesting you reduce your JavaScript file count. You should talk to the person who developed the build process. If there's no JavaScript processing in the build scripts, then you should certainly keep your JavaScript file count low for the sake of your users. If there is, and you think your coworker is full of it, you should create about 50 JavaScript files (fill them with some random JavaScript) and run a build. If the build time doesn't seem any longer, then you know your co-worker is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

war files are really just zip files with some special metadata and structure, so yes it will take longer in the sense that those files have to be compressed just like you were making a zip. However, that would be true of any type of file at all, there is nothing special about js files.